# Android custom action bar remove icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Below is a screenshot of my current setup.

[image]

I have created a custom action bar view, which I set in the code below, and what I would like is two images, one left aligned in the title bar, the other right aligned.

The problem is, that when I hide the app icon, it only hides it, not removes it hence the gap on the left. I found a couple of other SO questions that show how to remove the icon, but that also removes the tabs which I want to keep.

Can any one offer me a solution?

From my onCreate() function:

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);    

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_bar_title, null);

        View homeIcon = findViewById(android.R.id.home);
        ((View) homeIcon.getParent()).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ((View) homeIcon).setVisibility(View.GONE);        

        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);  
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setCustomView(v);
```

My xml custom layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >    

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/title_img_left"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"                    
                    android:src="@drawable/test" />
     <ImageView android:id="@+id/title_img_right"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/test" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm using the Holo.Light.DarkActionBar theme I believe.

Comment: this no iPhone. buttons in actionbar are supposed to be on the right side.

Comment: so, try inherite sherlock widget bar with your own style

Comment: @bofredo I don't understand what iPhone has to do with anything. They are not buttons they are images and that's how I would like them to look in the design

Comment: in android, the topleft image is by convention the place for the return-to-parent-view. and if you are just posting images why would you use the ACTION-bar for it?

Comment: @bofredo I'm new to Android and am unfortunately unaware of some of the "best practices". Are you suggesting I just use a normal view that sits above the actionbar then?

Comment: hmmm you could add some custom-icons into the actionbar and just make them unclickable. sry, maybe i dont get the idea of what you are trying to do :/

Comment: Essentially those two android Icons I want to be two separate logo images for my app (branding for the company). I don't mind how that is achieved.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand the thing which you are trying to achieve, why you just don't add a `MenuItem` with your custom image on left side and set you `actionBarLogo` with the image which you want to be on the right side. After that just override home button click and I guess you will achieve the same thing which you can create with custom view, without the padding on the left side of `ActionBar`.

**P.S.**   If I understand you wrong, please give some more information on how it should look like.

Answer (score 0):

the code is working!!!

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar();

        View customNav = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.custom_action_bar_view, null);
        ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) customNav.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

        ActionBar.LayoutParams lp = new ActionBar
            .LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        actionBar.setCustomView(customNav, lp);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```